# User created with ASP.Net Web Site Administration Tool is not stored in the Membership database

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a new MVC 4 Web Application with Visual Studio Express 2010. A membership database was automatically created on a local SQL Server express database 2008.

Database server: {local computer name}\SQLEXPRESS
Database name: aspnet-{project name}-{yyyymmddhhmmss}

When I ran the web application, I managed successfully to add a new user and the user was stored in the membership database. This means the web app was connected with membership database.

However, when I brought up the ASP.Net Web Site Administration Tool, it showed 0 user. Any new users that I created on the Admin Tool were not stored in the membership database.

Could anyone help with any idea about it? Thanks

By the way, the connection string in the web.config looks like:

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication-20140505092727;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: What does your web.config look like (removing usernames / passwords)?\